# How to fix click event & two autocomplete functions with jQuery in App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, autocomplete, onclicklistener

Updated: Solved it by rewriting autocomplete functions into one. Strange. The extra document.ready causing the problem.

I have 2 issues.

First, I'm running two autocomplete functions for clients & the other for employees. Let's label the client function as Field 1 & the employee's function as Field 2. When I typed the client's name in Field 1 who's name is spelled similarly to my employee's name, I get both the client's & the employee's names. The same goes for Field 2. Example: Client's: Aahliyah & Employee's: Aaina.

Second, when I click on the submit button, it works for some of the names. In Field 1, I typed Ana & David in Field 2. It works. But..When I typed John in Field 1 & Sara in Field 2..it doesn't work. I've tested click event functions before adding the libraries from materializecss.com site & they work. They also worked for a bit after adding the libraries & autocomplete functions. Now the click event only works for some names.

I'm using jQuery with Google App scripts.

Here's the click event & both autocomplete functions. I've included the libraries for jQuery and materializeCSS with notes of their position in the html.

```
  <!--Import Google Icon Font   Note: Top of Page-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQuery Note: Top of Page-->    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript Note: Bottom of Page -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <script>
      var date = $("#date")[0];
      var student = $("#student")[0];
      var appt = $("#time")[0];
      var tutor = $("#tutor")[0];  

      $("#btn")[0].addEventListener("click",addRecord);
      function addRecord(){
        var d = date.value;
        var s = student.value;
        var a = appt.value;
        var t = tutor.value;

          if(d.trim().length == 0 || s.trim().length == 0 || a.trim().length == 0 || t.trim().length == 0){       
          } else {
            var log = {
              date: date.value,
              student: student.value,
              appt: appt.value,
              tutor: tutor.value,

          };
          google.script.run.appendData(log);          
          student.value = "";
          appt.value = "";
          tutor.value = "";

        }//Close IF Statement
     }//Close addRecord

//Initialize autocomplete for clients
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tutor').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Arookian": null,
        "Ausen": null,
        "DaCh": null,
        "Da": null,
        "Dain": null,
        "Ele": null,
        "Hada": null,
        "Lyd": null,
        "Mat": null,
        "Mich": null,
        "Ni": null,
        "No": null,
        "Pat": null,
        "Re": null,
        "Sev": null,
        "Sha": null,
        "Taii":null,
        "Tan": null
      },
    });
  });


//Initialize autocomplete for Employees
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#student').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,        
      },
    });
  });

    </script>
```

Comment: Small point, but you only need one document.ready - all code you want to wait goes inside here (so both your inits)

Comment: True I'm just going to leave those in because it doesn't hurt it. Also, the code I provide is the latest one. I made copies of each code before adding anything. I know extra doc.ready doesn't hurt the last working copy.

Comment: Have you used unique label and ID pairing on each Autocomplete?

Comment: Yup. The issue was that I didn't assign a unique ID to specific which list to pull the names from & having multiple document.ready. It's fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Always good to rule out the simple stuff first :)

Comment: Also, feel free to 1) upvote my comments if they helped you find a solution and 2) post the solution as an answer so that anyone searching this in future can see how to fix it.